# How to get the Average from two tables SQL

Tags: sql-server, percentage, create-table

[image]

I have 2 tables Denials_Scrub_Final and Claims_Final
I want to get the percent for all the invoice.

That would be (Denials_Scub_Final/Claims_Final) *100
This would display a new table Percentage as a new table.

This should look like the excel screenshot which was manually done.
Last block Denial Rate.

[image]

Comment: Please add the DBMS name..

Comment: I would turn those 2 queries into views and then join on month and year and then run your formula on each column using the values for each school. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is no **SQL Server 18** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Comment: Please avoid using images for queries and data... use formatted text instead. As well as looking better, its then possible for people to copy and paste it out to try and assist you. People are less inclined to re-type is all in themselves.

Comment: SELECT 
A.Year,
A.Month,
CAST((COUNT(A.BCHO) * 100 / B.BCHO)as DECIMAL(10,8)) AS BCHO   
FROM Denials_Scrub_Final_V A
INNER JOIN  Claims_Final_V B
ON B.Year = A.Year
AND A.Month = B.Month
GROUP BY
A.Year,
A.Month,
A.BCHO
--------------------Column 'Claims_Final_V.BCHO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.----

Comment: MS SQL SERVER Management Studio 18

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is a client program, like you'd use Outlook (a client) to connect to Exchange (the server). What is the version of SQL Server? If you don't know trying executing `select @@version`.

Answer (score 0):

No final solution, but the approach should be clear.
Since we do not have the data from *Denials_Scrub_Final* or *Claims_Final* I generated some sample data. I am using a single table variable *@data* with some duplicates to generate the different numbers.

```
-- create sample data
declare @data table
(
    Yr int,
    Mth int,
    Center nvarchar(10),
    Invoice int
);

insert into @data (Yr, Mth, Center, Invoice) values
(2020, 1, 'ABC', 101),
(2020, 1, 'ABC', 101),
(2020, 1, 'ABC', 102),
(2020, 1, 'DEF', 201),
(2020, 1, 'DEF', 202),
(2020, 2, 'ABC', 103),
(2020, 2, 'ABC', 104),
(2020, 2, 'DEF', 203),
(2020, 3, 'ABC', 105),
(2020, 3, 'ABC', 105),
(2020, 3, 'ABC', 106),
(2020, 2, 'DEF', 204),
(2020, 2, 'DEF', 204),
(2020, 2, 'DEF', 205);
```

The **first data set**:

```
-- reproduce first query
select *
from ( select distinct Invoice, Center, Yr, Mth from @data ) BaseData
pivot ( count(Invoice) for Center in ([ABC], [DEF]) ) p;
```

gives

```
Yr          Mth         ABC         DEF
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2020        1           2           2
2020        2           2           3
2020        3           2           0
```

The **second data set**:

```
-- reproduce second query
select *
from ( select Invoice, Center, Yr, Mth from @data ) BaseData
pivot ( count(Invoice) for Center in ([ABC], [DEF]) ) p;
```

gives

```
Yr          Mth         ABC         DEF
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2020        1           3           2
2020        2           2           4
2020        3           3           0
```

Final **solution**: move the data sets in [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE's) and join them to apply the formula (use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) to avoid division by zero and [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to format the percentages):

```
-- combine queries in CTE's and apply formula
with cte_denial as
(
    select p.Yr, p.Mth, p.ABC, p.DEF
    from (  select distinct Invoice, Center, Yr, Mth from @data ) BaseData
    pivot ( count(Invoice) for Center in ([ABC], [DEF]) ) p
),
cte_claim as
(
    select p.Yr, p.Mth, p.ABC, p.DEF
    from (  select Invoice, Center, Yr, Mth from @data  ) BaseData
    pivot ( count(Invoice) for Center in ([ABC], [DEF]) ) p
)
select  c1.Yr,
        c1.Mth,
        convert(numeric(5,2), case when c2.ABC > 0 then c1.ABC*100.0/c2.ABC else 0 end) as 'ABC_%',
        convert(numeric(5,2), case when c2.DEF > 0 then c1.DEF*100.0/c2.DEF else 0 end) as 'DEF_%'
from cte_denial c1
join cte_claim c2
    on  c2.Yr = c1.Yr
    and c2.Mth = c1.Mth;
```

gives

```
Yr          Mth         ABC_%      DEF_%
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
2020        1           66.67      100.00
2020        2           100.00     75.00
2020        3           66.67      0.00
```